Python smtplib - Getting SMTPRecipientsRefused error
I am trying to build a code that sends an email with some data stored as html, and sends it over to a distribution email.
def sendEmail_htmlTable(self, subject, message):

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['emailFrom'] = 'noreply@test.com'
    msg['emailTo'] = '-this-is-a-test@exch.test.com'
    
    text = "Hi!\nError."
    html = """\
    <html>
      <p>Hello,</br>
      <p>testing table.</br>
      {0}
    </html>
    """.format(message)
    
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(msg['emailFrom'], msg['emailTo'], msg.as_string())
    print("Email sent")
    s.quit()

However, after executing, I get the following error message:
File "/usr/share/cdp/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 881, in sendmail
raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'-this-is-a-test@exch.test.com': (501, b'5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax')}

The code works with a personal email, but it did not work with the distribution email

Well your code looks fine (except maybe for the recipient address but I know nothing about it). The error was sent by the mail server and only displayed by you program. Said differently: ask your mail server admin for the reason. And if you are the mail server admin as it seems to be your local machine, ask yourself whether you could send a mail to that address from your usual mail reader...
